# В чём цель новомодного опускания местоимений?

Tags: местоимения

В последние несколько лет мне стала регулярно попадаться причудливая практика опускать местоимения. Например, банк присылает уведомление: «Продлили действие вашего промокода (...)». Или развлекательный портал называет статью: «Собрали для вас подборку (...)». На мой взгляд, в обоих случаях в начале предложения напрашивается «мы».

С какой целью здесь опускается местоимение? И удалось ли кому-то выяснить, откуда пошла эта практика?

Comment: Есть на примете первоисточник: "Уронили мишку на пол... все равно его не брошу..."

Comment: @Alex_ander В этом стихе пропуск местоимений подчёркивает неизвестность действующих лиц.

Comment: Я не увидел в ответах упоминания "Инфостиля". Это подход, который популяризировал копирайтер Максим Ильяхов, и одна из концепций там - так называемые "стоп-слова", то есть слова, которые можно опустить без потери смысла. В том числе и местоимения. Это довольно популярная тема в российском копирайтинге, а ваше примеры (уведомления, заголовок статьи в интернете) - как раз из этой сферы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, это от подсознательного стремления избежать личной ответственности (то ли "мы", написавшие, то ли "они", коллеги, - а вдруг что-то не так пойдёт?). Одно время, в середине 90-х, во всякое утверждение многие по той же причине вставляли "**как бы**" (возможно, говорящий и не совсем прав). В самое последнее время распространилось стремление говорящего на публику блогера или журналиста на всякий случай *извиняться* перед неопределенным кругом лиц.

Бывают и другие причины массовой деградации речи, наиболее яркой из которых стала в последние годы засоряющая её вставка "**в том числе**", подхваченная от политиков с пропагандистами и (преимущественно) спортивных журналистов, заполняющих этой конструкцией пустоты непрерывной речи. Первоначально же "в том числе" сопровождало агрессивную аргументацию в перепалке на ток-шоу и было вызвано подсознательной защитой от контраргумента вроде "если только это, то все наоборот!", дескать, у говорящего подобных аргументов много в запасе. Сейчас этим грешат даже некоторые литераторы.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, это связано с ростом популярности "быть инкогнито" [соблюдать анонимность] (в том числе не называть себя) на фоне слухов и фактов массовой слежки за пользователями (в том числе смартфонов) и распространением пиратства и всего нелегального, чем можно заниматься в сети.

В данных примерах также имеет место подсознательный уход от ответственности (так как не указано действующее лицо). Но не думаю, что это имеет всеобщий характер.

Answer (score 1):

> И удалось ли кому-то выяснить, откуда пошла эта практика?

«Эта практика» **предшествовала** нынешней «практике» маркировать субъектную референцию с помощью личных местоимений: в древнерусском языке ведущим типом маркирования субъектной референции были глагольные аффиксы, субъектные же местоимения существовали для особых случаев (эмфаза, контрастивное противопоставление и т. п.), а субъектные местоимения 3-го лица в древнерусских памятниках вообще наблюдаются только с XIII–XIV вв. — т. е. гораздо позже местоимений 1-го и 2-го лиц. (*Борковский В. И., Кузнецов П. С. Историческая грамматика русского языка. М., 2006, с. 322*).

Выглядела древнерусская «практика», например, так (1-я половина XII в.): *Чемоy не восолеши чето ти есемо водала ковати* («Почему (ты) не присылаешь то, что (я) дала тебе выковать?». — *Берестяные грамоты XI–XV вв. URL: http://gramoty.ru; Зализняк А. А. Древненовгородский диалект. М., 2004, с. 267.*)

Такой тип референциального маркирования был, помимо древнерусского, свойственен практически всем письменно засвидетельствованным индоевропейским языкам и в этой связи реконструируется и для общего предка (*Hopper P. J. The syntax of the simple sentence in Proto-Germanic. The Hague and Paris, 1975, р. 80; Adams D. Q., Mallory J. P. The Oxford introduction to proto-indo-european and indo-european world. Oxford, 2006, р. 60; Walkden G. Syntactic Reconstruction and Proto-Germanic. Oxford, 2014, р.230*). Глагольные связки, ранее выполнявшие в русском языке референциальную функцию, ныне им полностью утрачены. Причины и детали всего этого — тема интересная, но здесь явно совершенно неуместная.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, местоимения (особенно местоимение «я») для придания речи большей компактности иногда опускали с самого начала существования речи. Сейчас довольно многие не умеют опускать их грамотно, но сама по себе такая «практика» вполне имеет право на существование.

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, практика опускать местоимения существует испокон веку. В пример можно упомянуть безличные предложения: "Кушать подано!", "Ни в сказке сказать, ни пером описать".
Причудливо выглядит их новая форма: "Кушать подали!", "Ни в сказке сказали, ни пером описали".

Comment: А какое местоимение опустили в ваших первых двух примерах?

Comment: По всей видимости, "нами" и "нам" :) "Кушать подали" не так уж "причудливо" в контексте восклицания сидящих за столом. Причудливо было бы добавить "они".

Comment: Если пишущий ставит себе целью быть понятым однозначно, то у него получатся безличные предложения: «Действие вашего промокода продлено», «Для вас собрана подборка…». Если же цели такой нет, то получаются фразы - кастраты, в которых читатель должен угадывать пропущенное местоимение, например: Вам / Вы/ Они / Им /Мы (продлили действие вашего промокода).